# MUI ThemeProvider is not injecting theme in a compiled component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

So I have these two projects that use MUI. One of them contains only small functional components (a library) and the other imports the "library" of components via `yarn link`, and is supposed to apply a custom theme via the "ThemeProvider".

I use storybook for my list of components. In order to see that all works as expected I use storybook's plugin: 'storybook-addon-material-ui'.

Example code of how I define my stories:

```
storiesOf('Tile', module)
  .addDecorator(muiTheme([myCustomTheme]))
  .add('Default', withInfo()(() => (
    <div>
      <Tile title="Title goes here" />
    </div>
  )))
```

Storybook shows the exact results I want. My custom theme is also exported from the Library project. When I use it in my Work Project (the one that imports the library), I define the Theme via 
`import { ThemeProvider as MuiThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';` in the first possible wrapping component:

```
class Layout extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
         // Provider, Routing, etc
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    )
  }

}
```

The result: every single MUI component in my work project EXCEPT my library components is styled in my custom theme. However my custom components are styled in the base MUI theme that comes in core.

When I use the components they are already build with the script:

```
BABEL_ENV=production babel src -d lib --ignore src/**/*.story.jsx,src/**/*.spec.js,src/**/*.test.js
```

Am I missing some setting I need to give my custom components, so that they use the Theme provided my MUI?

Comment: Did you get any fix ? I am observing exact same issue.

Comment: Yes, I fixed it like the comment below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So this turned out to be the same bad behaviour that is observed in this very common issue: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13991. In my case, I had two instances of Material UI because of `yarn link`. I solved it by creating alias in my webpack:

```
config.resolve = {
  ...config.resolve,
  alias: {
    react: path.resolve("./node_modules/react"),
    '@material-ui': path.resolve("./node_modules/@material-ui")
  }
};
```

Comment: Observing the same, issue. Tried your solution on webpack file of shared library component, but not success. Any thing else to be done here ?

Comment: No, sorry, this worked for me. If however, you are using CRA, beware that you need to use a package like react-app-rewired in order for your webpack config to take place. Other than that, any changes are pointless.

Comment: didn't work for me, I am exporting a theme from the main folder and importing it in my common files through singleton design

Comment: If you're using it as a NPM package, consume material-ui as a peerDependency, rather than a dependency.

e.g:
If project A consumes project B, and both A & B use material UI, make sure that B has material-ui as a peerDependancy. That would mean A will expose material-ui to B. Eventually -> same instance.

You can set peerDependencies in package.json.

For development purposes (Surely, not production), you may need to add material-ui to devDependencies along with adding it to peerDependencies.

Comment: I lost a day to this, for future readers using v5 I was able to get this to work by adding the following alias in my webpack config: `'@mui/material': path.resolve('./node_modules/@mui/material')`