# Material-UI theme not working in shared-component

Tags: material-ui

I'm building a reusable shared-component library using material-ui which is being imported in my main app like this:

```
import { theme, StepperComponent } from '@company/shared-components';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';

...

return (
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
     <StepperComponent steps={stepperTitles} />
     ...
)
```

The stepper component is in my shared-components repository which I'm `npm-linking`

```
import React from 'react';
import Step from '@mui/material/Step';
import StepLabel from '@mui/material/StepLabel';
import { StyledStepper, StyledStepConnector, StyledStepIcon } from './Stepper.styles';

const StepperComponent = ({ steps, ...props }) => {
  return (
    <StyledStepper {...props} connector={<StyledStepConnector />} alternativeLabel>
```

However, for some reason the theme isn't getting applied to this component even though I'm wrapping it in the theme provider. When I log out the theme it doesn't include the colors that are in the theme being imported to my main app.

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: I am having similar issues. Would be curious to hear if you ever got around this

Comment: @pooley1994 I got exactly the same case. My solution was to wrap `ThemeProvider` (and utilize my theme) in a component of my own and then export it from my shared library to the consumers

Answer (score 2):

I'm dealing with something similar and haven't resolved it completely, but I have a strong feeling it involves multiple React contexts being created inside material-ui and emotion/react.

The `ThemeProvider` only exposes the theme to the components that have access to its context - the components within your main application.

I was able to achieve the desired behavior by making sure material-ui's ThemeProvider and it's context lives in the shared component library and not the main application. I did this by exporting a simple wrapper of ThemeProvider from the component library; literally just:

```js
interface LibraryThemeProviderProps {
  children?: React.ReactNode;
  theme: Theme;
}

const LibraryThemeProvider: React.FC<LibraryThemeProviderProps> = ({ children, theme }) => (
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    {children}
  </ThemeProvider>
)
```

and then using `LibraryThemeProvider` in the place of material's `ThemeProvider` in the main application.

If you want the same theme applied within your main application you only need to leave the original `ThemeProvider` in place alongside the new `LibraryThemeProvider`.

I'd prefer to solve this with a single `ThemeProvider` but haven't been able to yet :/

Note: I am using the `useTheme` hook inside all my components to access the theme. `useTheme` will use material's default theme if it doesn't see one provided by the ThemeProvider context - all this happens under the hood.

Comment: But isn't the context managed by the inner ThemeProvider overriding the context of the outer ThemeProvider? Why is it not sufficient to render only the ThemeProvider exported from the Theme?

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem recently. There were likely two copies of `@mui/material` loaded simultaneously.

If we symlinked the `@company/shared-components` package into `main-app` directly, all the packages defined in "devDependencies" will be included even though we have included them in "peerDependencies." Thus, resulting in the following dependency tree.

```
main-app
└─ node_modules
   ├─ @mui/material <-- ThemeProvider in the main app will load this
   └─ @company/shared-components
      └─ node_modules
         └─ @mui/material <-- Components from shared-components will load this
```

In my case, the solution for Webpack is to include `@mui/material` in [resolve.alias](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias) to mimic the notion of peer dependencies, which is to use the package installed in the `main-app`

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    '@mui/material': 'node_modules/@mui/material'
  }
}
```

**Related Questions**

1. [MUI ThemeProvider is not injecting theme in a compiled component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59820133/mui-themeprovider-is-not-injecting-theme-in-a-compiled-component)
2. [How to create a shared component library with MUI 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70696283/how-to-create-a-shared-component-library-with-mui-5)

Answer (score 0):

I also had a same problem, This is how I solved it.
In my case, I was using "rollup" to create the react library,
To solve this all I have to do was just provide libraries   "@emotion/react",
"@emotion/styled", as external dependency,

i mean in rollup.config.js file just update the external tag with below value

```
export default {
    entry: 'src/index.js',
    dest: 'bundle.js',
    format: 'cjs',
    external: [  "@emotion/react","@emotion/styled"]
};
```

https://rollupjs.org/troubleshooting/#warning-treating-module-as-external-dependency (bit of documentation on external dependency in rollup)

Whichever tool you are using to generate your library, check in the config file is there an option to provide external dependency and update it value and it should work

FYI using

```
"react": "18.2.0",
"@mui/material": "^5.13.0",
"@emotion/react": "^11.11.0",
"@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
```