# How to create a shared component library with MUI 5

Tags: material-ui

I have a custom MUI 5 component library NPM package that exports some basic components built with MUI 5, exports **theme** file and wraps the theme provider into reusable component like so:

```
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components';
import { StyledEngineProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { theme as defaultTheme } from './theme';

function CustomThemeProvider(props: {
  theme: any;
  children: JSX.Element[];
}): JSX.Element {
  const { theme = defaultTheme, children } = props;
  return (
    <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>{children}</ThemeProvider>
    </StyledEngineProvider>
  );
}

export default CustomThemeProvider;
```

However when I try using this custom theme provider and the components in the project that uses this shared library, theme is not applied at all. This approach did work with MUI 4, but there was no Emotion layer at that point and setup was much simpler.

I have added all of these in peer dependencies for the shared component package to keep the references intact.

```
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.7.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.6.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.2.4",
    "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.60",
    "@mui/styles": "^5.2.3",
    "@mui/material": "^5.2.4",
    "@mui/styled-engine-sc": "^5.1.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.3"
  },
```

But it does not make any difference.

Any ideas how to make it work, or any other approach that allows for a shared MUI 5 component library / theme to work, are welcome!

Comment: I have the same problem, have you found a solution?

Comment: @ludvigeriksson I did and I have added it in this article.

Comment: @ludvigeriksson were you able to find a solution?

Comment: @elstgav sorry, I don’t remember exactly but the problem was related to the library being imported from different node_modules folders, so it acted like two different “environments”.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if this is the same situation, but in my case this was a problem of using `npm link` for local development.

**NOTE:** You could also run into this problem if `@mui` is not listed as a `peerDependency` of your component package.

**TLDR:** If your shared component library package is installed with its own copy of `@mui` (i.e. `/node_modules/pkg/node_modules/@mui`) then your shared ThemeProvider won’t work.

---

I have a very similar setup, with a shared npm package (`@my/custom-components`) with MUI as a peer dependency. In the consuming app, I used `npm link @my/custom-components`.

The problem with using link is it creates a symlink to your local package, which isn’t representative of the final build. When `@my/custom-components` is published, it only includes the `package.json` and a `dist/` folder. But on my local machine, it includes all the source files, **including the `node_modules` folder**.

Normally, a package with peerDependencies won’t have its own sub `node_modules` folder, to ensure it uses the host app’s dependencies. But with this local setup, `@my/custom-components` was configuring its own copy of MUI, instead of the host app’s MUI:

```
// When using npm link

host-app
├── node_modules
│   ├── @my/custom-components
│   │   ├── dist
│   │   ├── node_modules
│   │   │   └── @mui/material-ui  <== conflicting copy
│   │   └── package.json
│   └── @mui/material-ui          <== host copy
├── src
└── package.json
```

```
// When installed normally

host-app
├── node_modules
│   ├── @my/custom-components
│   │   ├── dist
│   │   └── package.json
│   └── @mui/material-ui          <== only copy
├── src
└── package.json
```

To fix the problem, I:

1. Removed the sym link (`npm install` in the host app)
2. Manually built `@my/custom-components` (`npm pack`)
3. Replaced `host-app/node_modules/@my/custom-components` with the built package.

Comment: This was really helpful, thanks. In my case I needed to move @mui out of the dependencies in my package to peer dependencies. But essentially the same issue, two different versions of MUI

Comment: @Coltvant Glad it helped! I’ve updated the answer to mention `peerDependencies` 

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, what i did was,

create the theme project with custom build configurations with rollup. at their I added @mui/ as external packages. then export the mui5 theme provider.

then consumes it in the consumer project. consumer project need to have mui5 as dependencies. simple we are sharing the mui5.

sample rollup config ==>

```
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
```

import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2';

const packageJson = require('./package.json'); // eslint-disable-line @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires

```
export default {
  input: 'src/index.ts',
  external: [
    'react',
    'react-dom',
    'prop-types',
    '@emotion/react',
    '@emotion/styled',
    '@mui/lab',
    '@mui/icons-material',
    '@mui/material',
    '@mui/material/styles',
    '@mui/styles',
  ],
  output: [
    {
      file: packageJson.main,
      format: 'cjs',
      sourcemap: true,
    },
    {
      file: packageJson.module,
      format: 'esm',
      sourcemap: true,
    },
  ],
  plugins: [
    resolve(),
    commonjs(),
    typescript({ useTsconfigDeclarationDir: true }),
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem with a component built with Vite and MUI 5. In local testing the component didn't pick up the correct theme. It was due to the problem identified by @elstgav with npm link and nod_modules existing in the linked package folder.

I use Vite's alias resolve config (same as Rollup's resolve) to point to the correct node_modules.

**vite.config.js:**

```
resolve: {
  alias: [
    {
      find: /^(@mui\/[\w-]+)/,
      replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/$1"),
    },
  ],
},
```

Answer (score -2):

I have found a solution. Adding external theme provider was an overkill that I converted from MUI4.

In MUI 5 only thing that is needed is shared theme file. So place the theme file in the shared component library and import it in the projects that use it, but keep the theme providers local in all three codebases.

Comment: Dang, I have the same problem, but I wouldn’t really consider this a solution to your original question, it simply bypasses the problem. I’m still looking for a way to share a custom ThemeProvider…